# How to test WSO2 Message Broker with JMeter

Tags: jms, wso2, jmeter, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker

I'm having some issues getting JMeter to work against the WSO2 Message Broker using the JMS Publisher. I had JMeter working against ActiveMQ but I'm still new with the tool.

I copied the client libraries over to jmeter wso2mb-2.0.1\client-lib to apache-jmeter-2.9\lib

- andes-client-0.13.wso2v4.jar
- geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1.jar

Settings:

- Context Factory : org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
- Provider Url : amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'
- Connection Factory : qpidConnectionfactory

...also tried several other values

- Destination: dynamicQueues/test

The error I'm getting is on the Connection Factory field.
I've tried several different values all of which generate a naming error like there is a setting missing.
When I leave it blank I get:

> javax.naming.NamingException: Expected javax.jms.ConnectionFactory, found org.wso2.andes.jndi.ReadOnlyContext

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?
Suspect it's something simple.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

In short the qpid context factory `org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory` does not use fields the same way as the activeMQ context factory `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`.

While ActiveMQ allows you to not use a separate properties file with Jmeter, Qpid does not.

**Jmeter JMS Publisher:**

- Context Factory : org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory
- Provider Url : nameOfYouFile.properties
- Connection Factory : qpidConnectionfactory
- Destination : `<QueuePropertyName>`

**nameOfYouFile.properties:**

```
connectionfactory.qpidConnectionfactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5672'
queue.JMeterQueue = JMeterQueue
```

Reference:
[Qpid Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/qpid/how-to-use-jndi.html)